# Why when I want to add new rule to GeoServer GeoFence via RESTful API I got HTTP 406 error?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, geoserver-geofence

I'm trying to create a new rule in GeoServer GeoFence via GeoFence RESTful API, But I got HTTP 406 error, I don't know what thing I'm doing wrong, Because I did based on GeoServer GeoFence Plugin.

```
curl -v -u admin:g8****dg -X POST http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/geofence/rules -H "content-type:application/xml" -H "accept:application/xml" -d "
<Rule>
      <userName>demo@gmail.com</userName>
      <workspace>qwBCMzLk24L7nd1dWdizH4zl5nnckGYU</workspace>
      <layer>*</layer>
      <service>*</service>
      <request>*</request>
      <access>DENY</access> </Rule>"
```

```
curl -v -u admin:g8****dg -X POST http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/geofence/rules -H "content-type:application/json" -H "accept:application/json" -d '{"Rule":{"userName":"demo@gmail.com","roleName":"DEMO","workspace":"qwBCMzLk24L7nd1dWdizH4zl5nnckGYU","layer":"*","service":"*","request":"*","access":"DENY"}}'
```

I read these links also, But I didn't understand clearly and I didn't find a neat instruction that described step by step How users can create new Rule by GeoServer RESTful API

[GeoFence Tutorial in GeoServer Documnent](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geofence-server/tutorial.html) and [GeoFence github](https://github.com/geoserver/geofence)

I think the path mentioned that GeoServer GeoFence tutorial has a tiny mistake!, instead of http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/geofence/rules, there was http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geofence/rest/rules.

I did try both of them but I didn't get result.

What is the correct form of adding new rule to GeoFence (GeoServer version) via RESTful API?

I'm using GeoServer 2.20.2 and Tomcat 9.0.58, Java v8, Debian 11 x64,and GeoServer Geofence server plugin.

Comment: I think you need to PUT it rather than POST, and set the Content-type header to application/xml

Comment: Yes, your help was helpful, like always. when I removed "accept:application/xml" it worked. thank you so much

Comment: You should probably put that in as answer to help future users

Comment: thank you so much. @IanTurton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @IanTurton solution, He mentioned in comments.If run that command without "accept:application/xml" user will be able to add new rule.

The only header is need is **"content-type:application/xml"** or if you are trying to send json format use "content-type:application/json".

```
curl -v -u admin:g8****dg -X POST http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/geofence/rules -H "content-type:application/xml" 
-d "
<Rule>
     <userName>demo@gmail.com</userName>
  <workspace>
      qwBCMzLk24L7nd1dWdizH4zl5nnckGYU
  </workspace>
      <layer>*</layer>
      <service>*</service>
      <request>*</request>
      <access>DENY</access>
</Rule>"
```